# Migration options for preloaded sqlite database in iphone app

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data, migration

My app uses a preloaded SQLLite database with coredata bindings. I create the preloaded database file with a secondary app that has the core data bindings/model etc. I put the preloaded db into my app's resources folder and copy that to the writable documents folder when the app is first run.

My question is about migration. Since my app released, my users have been creating data and in my next release I want to change the data model and migrate some of the data to the new model. I'm just not sure the best way to do this. I've read about core data migration methods but they seem to require my app to be a core data project, which it isn't (though my secondary database-creating app is). Will I have to do this migration manually by issuing direct SQL statements against the db? And what about the core data bindings, will I have to manually update them?

I'm really just looking for pointers in the right/best direction. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLLite doesn't really have any data migration tools like Core Data.   Unless you count "ALTER TABLE".   If the migration is very complex, or you think you will have more complex migrations in the future you could make a Core Data model that more or less lines up with the old SQLite model and import to it, and then migrate to a newer Core Data model, and then stick with it.

This is likely slower then ALTER TABLE though, or at the very least "not faster".

Comment: I follow the "ALTER TABLE" part, which is kind of what I suspected I'd have to do. But I don't really understand what you mean by "you could make a Core Data model that more or less lines up with the old SQLite model and import to it, and then migrate to a newer Core Data model, and then stick with it." That seems interesting, can you elaborate? I am using Core Data bindings with my current SQLLite db, does this mean I've already done the part where I'd make a core data model that lines up with the old SQLLite model and import to it?

Comment: I don't know for sure without seeing your code, but yes it sounds like you have a core data model, just in another application.    There is still a lot of code to write, but it would be simpler code.   Unfortunately importing from SQLite to the older core data model and then having Core Data do a migration  is going to be slower then a by hand migration (either directly to a newer Core Data model, or to SQLite).   That may or may not be a showstopper depending on how long your users can be convinced to wait, or if you can do it in the background and have a useful subset of the app still work.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the advice.